# Finding Determinants Recursively

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, determinant

From the MIT OCW Linear Algebra (18.06) [final exam](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/final-exam/MIT18_06SCF11_final_exs.pdf), question 9:

> For square matrices with 3's on the diagonal, 2s on the diagonal
>   above, and 1s on the diagonal below:
>
> $$A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 3 \end{pmatrix}, A_2=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 1
>  & 3\\ \end{pmatrix}, A_3=\begin{pmatrix} 3&2&0\\ 1&3&2\\ 0&1&3\\
>  \end{pmatrix},... $$
>
> The determinant of $A_n$, $D_n$, can be defined recursively as:
>   $$D_n=aD_{n-1}+bD_{n-2}$$
>
> Find $D_5$ using eigenvalues.

I found $D_n=3D_{n-1}-2D_{n-2}$ and used 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
D_n\\
D_{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
D_{n-1}\\
D_{n-2}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $\begin{pmatrix}
D_2\\
D_1\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
7\\
3\\
\end{pmatrix}$

to solve:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
D_n\\
D_{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=(-1)1^n\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} + 2^n\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Plugging in $n=5$ gives $D-5=63$, but the answer key says $D_5=207$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should
$$\begin{pmatrix} D_2\\ D_1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 7\\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$
and not
$$\begin{pmatrix} D_2\\ D_1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 7\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo